# Why does robot_state_publisher skip publishing fixed joints

Tags: robot-state-publisher, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When attempting to do transforms on a kinematic model managed by robot_state_publisher I've noticed that fixed joints do not get published along with the tf data produced by `publishTransforms`.

This causes problems in anything relying on the transform chain like, among other things, rviz.

Why does this happen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11662/why-does-robot_state_publisher-skip-publishing-fixed-joints/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out as of Electric, the semantics of `publishTransforms` have changed and there is a separate call to publish fixed joints/transforms:

- `publishFixedTransforms`

Change happened here:
https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/robot_model/rev/5a3604a9031f

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-12-12**:
I got the impression from the wiki/tutorial that library was meant for end users/counts a public API. Not so?

**Comment by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on 2011-12-12**:
When you use the robot state publisher as a ROS node, the functionality should not have changed, and all old code should still work. If you are using the internal API of the state publisher, then this is indeed a breaking change.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-12-12**:
That makes sense, but the semantics seem to have changed from diamondback to electric with no change in signature/warning. That would cause silent failure in code written to the old semantics. Not sure if it makes sense to file a ticket now, as any fix would cause a second semantic change. Opinion?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-12-12**:
This allows you to not publish the fixed transforms as fast as the dynamic ones, saving bandwidth.